# Data relation in R plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, relationship

I have a data set in `R`, i.e the `Iris` dataset and I plot the first variable against all others with the following code

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
df <- iris
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (i in seq(ncol(df))[-1]) {
  plot(df[, 1], df[, i], xlim=range(5.5:8),xlab = colnames(df)[i],ylab = "Y")
  }
```

I use the `xlim` to remove data that do not display a specific pattern. How can I include a line/curve that shows the relation of the data, (*i.e to display a linear relationship or an exponential*). Is there any other way to make the plots more "presentable" but still displaying the relation of the data?

Comment: You should not need to call `library(datasets)`, nor use `data(iris)`, nor assign `iris` to a variable `df`. `iris` is simply available in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `abline` to show a linear regression line of the function `lm` using the following code:

```r
df <- iris
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (i in seq(ncol(df))[-1]) {
  # plt
  plot(df[, 1], df[, i], xlim=range(5.5:8), xlab = colnames(df)[i],ylab = "Y")
  # Add regression line
  abline(lm(df[, i] ~ df[, 1], data = df), col = "red")
}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>